# jquery cycle and greybox conflict

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Slideshow script of jquery cycle   (http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle/)   and pop-up window script of greybox (http://orangoo.com/labs/GreyBox/)  conflict when used together making the slide show nonfunctional with only the first image visible.

Any solution?

Comment: What do you mean non-functional? Have you got any code we can look at? Usually the case here would be a z-index issue when graybox displays the overlay

Comment: @JohnP, 'nonfunctional' means there is no slide show. suppose 4 images were to be shown in the slide show, but only the first one is shown instead. cycle script is used for a slide show whereas greybox is used for another part of the site but both scripts are used in the same page.

Comment: I understand the meaning of the word. What I am asking for is the context. Do you get an error message? Have you checked whether both plugins are firing? Does it stop on error?

Comment: @JohnP , wow! I got it solved. I just used the $.noConflict(): for the jquery cycle plugin.(http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/)

Answer (score -1):

use `noConflict()` method in build in jQuery method.
use like below ..

```
$.noConflict();
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
 code ...
});
```